# pre-Installation Script for an MSI package

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-installer, installation

I have created an .vbs script which executes some actions(i.e close some processes etc) and later executes a msi installation. I want to find a way to merge this .vbs script inside the package so the user when will run the setup.exe will execute first the script.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better served by putting those actions in the MSI so that they can be part of the Windows Installer transaction. The WiX toolset provides custom actions to close or restart appliciations (see the `[CloseApplication][1]` and `[RestartResource][2]` elements) so it would be easy to get those requirements solved.